# CSS output different on IE11 Windows7 vs IE11 Windows10

Tags: html, css, html-lists

```css
h2 {
 text-align: center;
}

.sections {
 border-top: 2px solid black;
 border-bottom: 2px solid black;
 text-align: center;
}

.header {
 border-top: 2px solid black;
}

.other {
 border-top: 2px solid black;
 border-bottom: 2px solid black;
}

body{
 background-color: #e7e7e7;
 border-style: double;
 border-color: #000000;
}

links{
 margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
}

li {
 list-style-type: none;
 margin: 7px 0;
} 
 
.GEN {
 display: inline-block;
 height: 32px;
 width: 200px;
 background: #767779;
 border: 2.5px solid #000000;
 color: #e7e7e7;
 text-align: center;
 font: bold 1.2em/15px "Helvetica Neue", Arial, Helvetica, Geneva, sans-serif;
 box-shadow: 0 8px 0 #1b383b;
 text-shadow: 0 2px 2px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
 border-radius: 50px;
 padding-top: 12px;
}
a.GEN {
 text-decoration: none;
}
.GEN:hover {
 text-decoration: underline;
 color: #000000;
 background-color: lightgrey;
}

.ORACLE {
 display: inline-block;
 height: 34px;
 width: 180px;
 background: #767779;
 border: 2.5px solid #000000;
 color: #e7e7e7;
 text-align: center;
 font: bold 1.3em/17px "Helvetica Neue", Arial, Helvetica, Geneva, sans-serif;
 box-shadow: 0 8px 0 #1b383b;
 text-shadow: 0 2px 2px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
 border-radius: 50px;
 padding-top: 10px;
}
a.ORACLE {
 text-decoration: none;
}
.ORACLE:hover {
 text-decoration: underline;
 color: #000000;
 background-color: lightgrey;
}

.IT {
 display: inline-block;
 height: 32px;
 width: 140px;
 background: #767779;
 border: 2.5px solid #000000;
 color: #e7e7e7;
 text-align: center;
 font: bold 1.3em/16px "Helvetica Neue", Arial, Helvetica, Geneva, sans-serif;
 border-radius: 50px;
 padding-top: 12px;
 box-shadow: 0 8px 0 #1b383b;
 text-shadow: 0 2px 2px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
}
a.IT {
 text-decoration: none;
}
.IT:hover {
 text-decoration: underline;
 color: #000000;
 background-color: lightgrey;
}

.HR {
 display: inline-block;
 height: 34px;
 width: 130px;
 background: #767779;
 border: 2.5px solid #000000;
 color: #e7e7e7;
 text-align: center;
 font: bold 1.2em/16px "Helvetica Neue", Arial, Helvetica, Geneva, sans-serif;
 border-radius: 50px;
 padding-top: 12px;
 box-shadow: 0 8px 0 #1b383b;
 text-shadow: 0 2px 2px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);

}
a.HR {
 text-decoration: none;
}
.HR:hover {
 text-decoration: underline;
 color: #000000;
 background-color: lightgrey;
}

.DCTPSL {
 display: inline-block;
 height: 30px;
 width: 240px;
 background: #767779;
 border: 2.5px solid #000000;
 color: #e7e7e7;
 text-align: center;
 font: bold 1.2em/14px "Helvetica Neue", Arial, Helvetica, Geneva, sans-serif;
 border-radius: 50px;
 padding-top: 15px;
 box-shadow: 0 8px 0 #1b383b;
 text-shadow: 0 2px 2px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);

}
a.DCTPSL {
 text-decoration: none;
}
.DCTPSL:hover {
 text-decoration: underline;
 color: #000000;
 background-color: lightgrey;
}

.FAC {
 display: inline-block;
 height: 36px;
 width: 190px;
 background: #767779;
 border: 2.5px solid #000000;
 color: #e7e7e7;
 text-align: center;
 font: bold 1.2em/16px "Helvetica Neue", Arial, Helvetica, Geneva, sans-serif;
 border-radius: 50px;
 padding-top: 10px;
 box-shadow: 0 8px 0 #1b383b;
 text-shadow: 0 2px 2px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
}
a.FAC {
 text-decoration: none;
}
.FAC:hover {
 text-decoration: underline;
 color: #000000;
 background-color: lightgrey;
}

.DCTPSS {
 display: inline-block;
 height: 40px;
 width: 200px;
 background: #767779;
 border: 2.5px solid #000000;
 color: #ffffff;
 text-align: center;
 margin: auto;
 font: bold 1.0em/16px "Helvetica Neue", Arial, Helvetica, Geneva, sans-serif;
 border-radius: 50px;
 padding-top: 10px;
 box-shadow: 0 8px 0 #1b383b;
 border-color: #00cc00;
 text-shadow: 0 2px 2px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
}
a.DCTPSS {
 text-decoration: none;
}
.DCTPSS:hover {
 text-decoration: underline;
 background-color: #00cc00;
 color: #000000;
 border-color: #000000;
}

.XER {
 display: block;
 height: 36px;
 width: 200px;
 background: #767779;
 border: 2.5px solid #000000;
 color: #ffffff;
 text-align: center;
 font: bold 1.2em/18px "Helvetica Neue", Arial, Helvetica, Geneva, sans-serif;
 border-radius: 50px;
 padding-top: 15px;
 box-shadow: 0 8px 0 #1b383b;
 border-color: red;
 text-shadow: 0 2px 2px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);

}
a.XER {
 text-decoration: none;
}
.XER:hover {
 text-decoration: underline;
 background-color: red;
 color: #000000;
 border-color: #000000;
}

.GSCB {
 display: block;
 height: 40px;
 width: 200px;
 background: #767779;
 border: 2.5px solid #000000;
 color: #ffffff;
 text-align: center;
 font: bold 1.0em/16px "Helvetica Neue", Arial, Helvetica, Geneva, sans-serif;
 box-shadow: 0 8px 0 #1b383b;
 text-shadow: 0 2px 2px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
 border-radius: 50px;
 padding-top: 10px;
 border-color: #ff6600;
}
a.GSCB {
 text-decoration: none;
} 
.GSCB:hover {
 text-decoration: underline;
 background-color: #ff6600;
 color: #000000;
 border-color: #000000;
}

.GSCBPL {
 display: block;
 height: 40px;
 width: 200px;
 background: #767779;
 border: 2.5px solid #000000;
 color: #ffffff;
 text-align: center;
 font: bold 1em/15px "Helvetica Neue", Arial, Helvetica, Geneva, sans-serif;
 border-radius: 50px;
 padding-top: 10px;
 box-shadow: 0 8px 0 #1b383b;
 border-color: #dea767;
 text-shadow: 0 2px 2px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
}
a.GSCBPL {
 text-decoration: none;
}
.GSCBPL:hover {
 text-decoration: underline;
 background-color: #dea767;
 color: #000000;
 border-color: #000000;
}

.TTL {
 display: block;
 height: 32px;
 width: 200px;
 background: #767779;
 border: 2.5px solid #000000;
 color: #ffffff;
 text-align: center;
 font: bold 1em/11px "Helvetica Neue", Arial, Helvetica, Geneva, sans-serif;
 border-radius: 50px;
 padding-top: 18px;
 box-shadow: 0 8px 0 #1b383b;
 border-color: #0066ff;
 text-shadow: 0 2px 2px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
}
a.TTL {
 text-decoration: none;
}
.TTL:hover {
 background-color: #0066ff;
 text-decoration: underline;
 color: #000000;
 border-color: #000000;
}

.LAX {
 display: block;
 height: 34px;
 width: 200px;
 background: #767779;
 border: 2.5px solid #000000;
 color: #ffffff;
 text-align: center;
 font: bold 1.1em/13px "Helvetica Neue", Arial, Helvetica, Geneva, sans-serif;
 border-radius: 50px;
 padding-top: 14px; 
 box-shadow: 0 8px 0 #1b383b;
 border-color: brown;
 text-shadow: 0 2px 2px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
}
a.LAX {
 text-decoration: none;
}
.LAX:hover {
 text-decoration: underline;
 background-color: brown;
 color: #000000;
 border-color: #000000;
}

.PSR {
 display: block;
 height: 34px;
 width: 200px;
 background: #767779;
 border: 2.5px solid #000000;
 color: #ffffff;
 text-align: center;
 font: bold 1.2em/15px "Helvetica Neue", Arial, Helvetica, Geneva, sans-serif;
 border-radius: 50px;
 padding-top: 20px;
 box-shadow: 0 8px 0 #1b383b;
 border-color: #7d26cd;
 text-shadow: 0 2px 2px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
}
a.PSR {
 text-decoration: none;
}
.PSR:hover {
 text-decoration: underline;
 background-color: #7d26cd;
 color: #ffffff;
 border-color: #000000;
}

.S3UL {
 display: block;
 height: 34px;
 width: 200px;
 background: #767779;
 border: 2.5px solid #000000;
 color: #ffffff;
 text-align: center;
 font: bold 1.1em/15px "Helvetica Neue", Arial, Helvetica, Geneva, sans-serif;
 border-radius: 50px;
 border-color: #7feaff;
 padding-top: 15px; box-shadow: 0 8px 0 #1b383b;
 text-shadow: 0 2px 2px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
}
.S3UL:hover {
 text-decoration: underline;
 background-color: #7feaff;
 color: #000000;
 border-color: #000000;
}
a.S3UL {
 text-decoration: none;
}
 
.S3A {
 display: block;
 height: 34px;
 width: 200px;
 background: #767779;
 border: 2.5px solid #000000;
 color: #ffffff;
 text-align: center;
 font: bold 1.1em/15px "Helvetica Neue", Arial, Helvetica, Geneva, sans-serif;
 border-radius: 50px;
 padding-top: 15px;
 box-shadow: 0 8px 0 #1b383b;
 border-color: #FFFF6B;
 text-shadow: 0 2px 2px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
}
.S3A:hover {
 text-decoration: underline;
 background-color: #FFFF6B;
 color: #000000;
 border-color: #000000;
}
a.S3A {
 text-decoration: none;
}


ul.LINKS1 {
 display: inline-block;
 list-style-position: inside;
 font-size: 19px;
 text-align: left;
 overflow:hidden;
}
ul.LINKS2 {
 display: inline-block;
 list-style-position: inside;
 font-size: 19px;
 text-align: left;
 overflow:hidden;
}
ul.LINKS3 {
 display: inline-block;
 list-style-position: inside;
 font-size: 19px;
 text-align: left;
 overflow:hidden;
}

ul.COLUMN1 {
 display: inline-block;
 list-style-position: inside;
 font-size: 19px;
 text-align: left;
 overflow:hidden;
}
ul.COLUMN2 {
 display: inline-block;
 list-style-position: inside;
 font-size: 19px;
 text-align: left;
 overflow:hidden;
}
ul.COLUMN3 {
 display: inline-block;
 list-style-position: inside;
 font-size: 19px;
 text-align: left;
 overflow:hidden;
} 
ul.COLUMN4 {
 display: inline-block;
 list-style-position: inside;
 font-size: 19px;
 text-align: left;
 overflow:hidden;
}
ul.COLUMN5 {
 display: inline-block;
 list-style-position: inside;
 font-size: 19px;
 text-align: left;
 overflow:hidden;
}
ul.COLUMN6 {
 display: inline-block;
 list-style-position: inside;
 font-size: 19px;
 text-align: left;
 overflow:hidden;
}
```

```html
<br>
<center><img src="hidden" width="660" height="240"></a></center>
</header>
<center><iframe src="http://free.timeanddate.com/clock/i645j8z3/n78/tlie/fs20/tce7e7e7/pce7e7e7/ftb/pa8/tt0/tm1/td2/th2/tb4" frameborder="0" width="255" height="62"></iframe></center>
<div class="sections">
<center>
<ul class="COLUMN1"><li><a href="" class="GEN">General Links</a></li></ul>
<ul class="COLUMN4"><li><a href="" class="ORACLE">Oracle Links</a></li></ul>
<ul class="COLUMN2"><li><a href="" class="IT">IT Links</a></li></ul>
<ul class="COLUMN3"><li><a href="" class="HR">HR Links</a></li></ul>
<ul class="COLUMN5"><li><a href="" class="DCTPSL">DCTP Systems Links</a></li></ul>
<ul class="COLUMN6"><li><a href="" class="FAC">Facilities Links</a></li></ul>
</center>
</div>
<center>
<h2><u>Quick Links</u></h2>

<ul class="LINKS1">
<li><a href="" class="GSCBPL">A</a></li>
<br><li><a href="" class="GSCB">B</a></li>
<br><li><a href="" class="XER">C</a></li>
</ul>

<ul class="LINKS2">
<li><a href="" class="TTL">D</a></li>
<br><li><a href="" class="PSR">E</a></li>
<br><li><a href="" class="LAX">F</a></li>
</ul>

<ul class="LINKS3">
<li><a href="" class="DCTPSS">G</a></li>
<br><li><a href="" class="S3A">H</a></li>
<br><li><a href="" class="S3UL">I</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="other">
<h2><a href="">More Links</a></h2> 
</div>

<footer>
<p><b><center>If you have any issues with this page, feel free to Contact me</center></b>
<br>

</p>
</footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Okay so i'm designing a local page that will be accessed by many people on a local network using Windows7 and Windows10. All PC's have latest version of IE11 installed.

The page looks the way i want it to on windows 10, (IE11 and Chrome).
But looks completely different on Windows 7 (IE11 and Chrome).

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

[How the page looks on Windows10](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pkXs0.png)

[How the page looks on Windows7](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WpcTn.png)

Comment: Are you running it on compatibility mode on windows 7?

Comment: Nope... don't post screenshots of your code (or even worse, links to screenshots of your code). Post your code.

Comment: Apologies, new to this. Code added.

Comment: It works on windows7 when i edit Compatibily view settings. is there a way to do this automatically rather than everyones PC?

Comment: You open <center> just above the quick links but it's never closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=11,chrome=1" />
```

Thanks for your help